# CSS3 transform:translate produces inaccurate results

Tags: html, css

I was trying to position the right edge of a div element 300px from the center of the page with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="login">
       <!-- login area -->
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

div#login {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(300px, 0px);
}
```

However, strangely, this results in the div being moved to the right by 374px.

Is there anything I forgot to think about?
Or is there a better way to reach the same result?

Comment: It's about 144px wide. I already tried different values of `transform-origin`, no visible change.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using `transform` -

use `right: calc(50% - 300px);`

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmp9knom/1/) first

Now check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmp9knom/2/)

*don't forget to widen the jsfiddle result window to see the result properly*

Hope this works as you want. If this doesn't work then please feel free to share it, also check if another CSS is overriding some styles of the `div`, I doubt this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turned out, the problem was not CSS, but Windows 10 settings. Be careful when measuring screenshots in GIMP while having set the general display size at 125%...

After that, all solutions worked fine, thanks!